# A passed Variable not shown in a blade - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

As I click the link in results2 blade, the incoming variable (which holds 'Test Text') is passed fine, but this value does not display in the dashboard2 blade.

The link in results2 blade:

```
<a href="{{route('dashboard2',['wordsRow'=> $wordsRow->body])}}">{{$wordsRow->body}}</a>
```

in Dashboard2 view  :

```
@if (isset($wordsRow))
            <header><h3>{{$wordsRow}}</h3></header>
@endif
```

URL of the Dashboard2 :

http://localhost/xxxxxxx/dashboard2?wordsRow=Test+text

Any help determining why 'Test Text' is not shown in the dashboard2 view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@if (Request::has('wordsRow'))
            <header><h3>{{Request::get('wordsRow')}}</h3></header>
@endif
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';'        in the line  :   @if (Request::has('wordsRow'))

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen somewhere, that Laravel passes $_GET variables automatically to a view. So where is the code for passing these variables to the views?

Comment: public function postWords(Request $request)

  {

$body = $request['body'];
$wordsRow = Words::where(DB::raw('body'),'LIKE', "%{$body}%")->get();

$words = new Words();
        $words->body = $body;

$request->user()->words()->save($words);

 return view('results2', [
   
    'wordsRow' => $wordsRow]);

  }

Comment: Well, how you pass the variable to the dashboard2-view is still missing. Maybe the below answer from huuuk already helps you out.